# how spring property resolver works?

Tags: java, spring

I have property place holder in my spring context.xml file

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="com.techpleiad.poc.RMCPropertyUtil">
        <property name="basenames" value="file:${config.file.dir}/prop_application" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="30"></property>
    </bean>
```

and this property '*config.file.dir*' is not getting resolved.

'config.file.dir' is the **environment variable** and when i debug the code and check for the basename the file path comes as it is.. '*{config.file.dir}/prop_application*'

I need to know what spring code/classes are involved in resolving such properties. 
How i could debug and resolve this problem?

Comment: Clarify _is not getting resolved_? Is the value of `basenames` literally `file:${config.file.dir}/prop_application`? Or do you get an exception?

Comment: Is `config.file.dir` in a property file?

Comment: edited the question.. hopes it clarifies the problem statement..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to register a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` with a reference to your property sources (or not since this is an environment property which are implicitly added).

With XML you can do that with

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring.properties" />
```

With Java config, simply define a `static` `@Bean` annotated method which returns a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Spring SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) to get the system properties

```
#{systemProperties['config.file.dir']}
```

To read environment variable use

```
#{systemEnvironment['config.file.dir']}
```

---

The `systemEnvironment` property contains all the environment variables on the machine where the program is running. Meanwhile, the `systemProperties` contains all the properties that we set in Java when the application started, using the `-D` argument.